# Setting URL as key for NSCache not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, nscache

I extended NSCache and created a Singleton class as below

```
+(instancetype)sharedDataCache {
if (!sharedDataCache) {
    sharedDataCache = [[QDataCache alloc] init];
    [sharedDataCache setTotalCostLimit:19999];
    [sharedDataCache setCountLimit:15];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:sharedDataCache selector:@selector(removeAllObjects) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
}
return sharedDataCache;
}
```

Setting Object in one class:

```
[_cache setObject:receivedData forKey:[[connection currentRequest]URL]];
```

and 
Getting object in other class:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[_caches objectForKey:keyString]];//keystring is the url
```

Both keys are same in log but I am getting NULL :( . 'IF I HARDCODE THE KEY WITH SAME STRING IT IS WORKING FINE'. But I want unique key (URL). Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you check that URL is NSString? not an NSURL?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put value by NSURL key, and then get the value by NSString key. The hash of NSURL object and NSString object is not the same.

You should do either

```
[_cache setObject:receivedData forKey:[[[connection currentRequest]URL] absoluteString]];
```

Or

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[_caches objectForKey:[NSURL URLWithString:keyString]]];
```

Comment: Thank you, Thats one of the mistakes I made. Another one is my cache limit... It was just 25 so the object got removed...